# It is possible to use glassfish as front end to other servers? How?

Tags: glassfish

As it is done with Apache and mod_jk to access applications without the need to type the port numbers, but i want to do it with Glassfish. Ff possible how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible because it doesn't make sense. Glassfish is an application server and not intended for use as a reverse proxy. There are other tools which perfectly fit for this job, like Apache, Nginx or Squid.

> without the need to type the port numbers, but i want to do it with
>   Glassfish

For applications running on Glassfish, you can do this by changing the port of the specific http-listener to 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS).

**See also:**

- [How can I use Glassfish under Linux as a reverse-proxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/104286/how-can-i-use-glassfish-under-linux-as-a-reverse-proxy)

Comment: thanks, i indeed changed the ports to 80 and 443, but the boss told we would use apache on port 80 end use it as front end, i just got curious if it could be done.